# how to create an C Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

his guys,

i think this is a simple question but i do not know how to do it.

how do i create the line below dynamically from an array?

this is what i need to call.

```
    //data source   
NSString * sourceData[7] = {@"2", @"1", @"4", @"8", @"14", @"15", @"10"};


chartData = [WSData dataWithValues:[WSData arrayWithString:sourceData  withLen:7]];




+ (NSArray *)arrayWithString:(NSString *[])strings
                     withLen:(NSUInteger)len {
    NSMutableArray *tmpArr = [NSMutableArray
                              arrayWithCapacity:len];
    NSUInteger i;

    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        [tmpArr addObject:strings[i]];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:tmpArr];
}
```

thanks for all the help especially Daniel :)

this is the answer to the question

```
NSMutableArray * dayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
dayArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];

NSMutableArray * sdArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
sdArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];

NSInteger drunked = [appDelegate.drinksOnDayArray count];

if (drunked !=0) 
{


for(int i=6; i>=0; i--) 
{
    DayOfDrinks *drinksOnDay = [appDelegate.drinksOnDayArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString * dayString= [NSDate stringForDisplayFromDateForChart:drinksOnDay.dateConsumed];

    [dayArray addObject:dayString];//X label for graph the day of drink.

    drinksOnDay.isDetailViewHydrated = NO;

    [drinksOnDay hydrateDetailViewData];

    NSNumber *sdNumber =  drinksOnDay.standardDrinks;
    [sdArray addObject: sdNumber];      
}

NSString *sData[7];// = malloc(7 * sizeof(NSString *));
for (int i=0; i<7; i++) 
{
    DayOfDrinks *drinksOnDay = [appDelegate.drinksOnDayArray objectAtIndex:i];
    sData[i] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",drinksOnDay.standardDrinks];

}

NSString * sourceData[7] = {sData[6],sData[5],sData[4],sData[3],sData[2],sData[1],sData[0] };
```

}

Comment: Do you want to create a C array or an NSArray?  What is the source of the values?  Do you know how to write a `for` loop?

Comment: hi Daniel,

Thanks for the reply,the source value is NSDecimal.

i know how to do a for loop.

i have this loop to get the graph label value for my X Bar.
i need the value of my chartData = [WSData dataWithValues:[WSData arrayWithString:sourceData  withLen:7]];

but i do not know how should i do it. please help me thanks :)

Comment: But you haven't told us whether then array is a C array or an NSArray.  Presumably a C array, since that's what you show in the first line of your post.  But do you know the array size, or must it be dynamic?

Comment: hi Daniel,

Just updated my code for the for loop array.

i have wanna create this graph http://dl.dropbox.com/u/418769/graph2.png

the array size is standard 7, as i need to know the last 7 days record. i'm pretty bad in converting stuff.i still pretty new in ios programming, i'm not too sure wats the diff of C array or NSArray

Comment: A "C array" is the sort of array you'd declare in C.  Eg, `SomeType someArray[7]`.  An NSArray is an Objective-C object.  You need to have a good understanding of both (and the difference between them) before you do much programming in Objective-C.

Comment: Would you kindly provide us with the prototype of the function you wish to call.

Comment: Hi Daniel,

Thanks for the explanation, yes i need a C Array.

Sorry for not asking a question clearly.

i have update the function for ur perusal thanks

Comment: Of course, you still haven't included the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only using the array as a call parm, and are not storing it somewhere or returning it from your current method:

```
NSString* sourceData[7];

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    int num = <getTheValueYouWant>;
    sourceData[i] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num];
}
```

But note that if you intend to return the array, or store it in some long-lived variable, you need an entirely different setup.

Comment: It's the type of array that you can get in C.  As distinguished from an NSArray, which is not a C array.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how you would create an NSMutableArray. Mutable because you're creating it at runtime.

```
    NSString * sourceData = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];

    //assuming the array you have is arr with NSNumber objects
    for (NSNumber *num in arr) {
        [sourceData stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", num];
    }
```

Comment: hi Manish, thanks for the reply

if base on ur line, will it create a String that looks like this 

NSString * sourceData[7] = {@"2", @"1", @"4", @"8", @"14", @"15", @"10"}; ??????/

Comment: Eeks ... I didn't realize you wanted to create that string. Let me edit my post

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about it being a C array. Please make your question clear.

Comment: The OP keeps saying "like this" and showing a C array.  So I'm assuming he wants (or thinks he wants) a C array.  But I suspect he doesn't know what he wants.

Comment: Hi Manish, thanks for the reply.

Sorry for not asking the question clearly.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code with the loop as you required.....

```
NSMutableArray *array;
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
[array release];
```